# "ggtern" Ternary plot gridlines and axis ticks needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, ternary, gridlines, ggtern

I am trying to add gridlines and axis ticks to the ternary plot. I was able to adjust the numeric values of the axis, but unable to get axis ticks and grids inside the plot.

Here is an example R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Example data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z<-rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# Create scatter plot with grid lines
ggtern(df, aes(x, y, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_showgrid()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey", linetype = "dashed"),
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey", linetype = "dashed"))
```

I am getting this

[image: Output Plot]

I want this

[image: Desired Plot]

Comment: It looks like a bug, the code in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138239/add-a-buffer-around-a-point-in-a-ternary-diagram is also not displaying the grid. Maybe a recent ggplot update broke the code.  What version of ggplot2 do you have installed?  Try downloading a previous version of ggplot to see if that fixes the problem.  I would try "nick@ggtern.com".

Comment: Thank you for the response. The above code is from ggplot2_3.4.0. I tried an older version of ggplot2_3.3.6 package it did not support ggtern.  I tried installing the older version of ggtern and unfortunately, it did not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an older version `3.3.5` from `ggplot2` and use `theme_bw` like this:

```r
library(remotes)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.3.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
#> Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)

# Example data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z<-rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# Create scatter plot with grid lines
ggtern(df, aes(x, y, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried ggplot2 3.3.5 and ggtern 3.3.5. It's not working.

Comment: The code works perfectly on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ with R version 4.0.3. I tried installing an older version of R on my PC, but the package doesn't work. @Quinten

Comment: I used R version 4.2.2, so maybe you could try with that version? Also please make sure you try this with a clean environment.

Answer (score 1):

This script worked

```
library(remotes)

install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.3.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
#> Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz
library(ggplot2)

install_version("ggtern", version = "3.3.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(ggtern)

# Example data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z<-rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# Create scatter plot with grid lines
ggtern(df, aes(x, y, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()+theme_showgrid()
```